# Jquery post data 3 times

Tags: php, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").bind('click', $.proxy(function (event) {
        var id = $(event.target).attr('id');
        var go = jQuery.isNumeric(id);
        if (go) {
            $.post("favswrite.php", {
                id: id
            });
            alert('Formül '+id+' favorilerinize eklendi !');
        }
    }, this));
});
```

This code is post data 3 times.
Where is wrong and loop it  ? I want post data 1 times.

Comment: Probably because you click somewhere where there are 3 nested divs and the event propagates to each of them. (See [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).)

Comment: Thanks Juhana :)It works! Good codings...